# Expo / React Native: Video Failing to Resize

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, video, expo

I'm using Expo with React Native, testing on the Android simulator on a Galaxy S8+.

I'm using the `Video` component from the Expo library, as I couldn't get `react-native-video` to work.

I'm using the following code: 
`<Video style={styles.video} source={{ uri: url }} isMuted={false} shouldPlay isLooping usePoster={true} useNativeControls={false} resizeMode="contain" />`

`styles.video` is simply `{width: window.width, height: 650}`

Which displays the following: [Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFtP2.jpg)

But, if you load the video in, it actually fits the whole window and is sized the way I want, but only for half a second. After that it immediately goes small like in the screenshot. I've tried `cover` and `center` as well, and it hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: More Details:**

What I want it to look like is something like this, which I have working for images: [Image of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZhRU.jpg)

With images, I'm using the default `Image` component from React Native in the following way: `<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: data.url }} resizeMode="contain" />`

And `styles.images` is identical to `styles.video` at the moment.

Comment: should the height be specified in pixels? height: 650px

Comment: Please share a sample design of your screen or denote where exactly you want to place the Video Player !

Comment: Also, should that be window.innerWidth ? instead of window.width
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Comment: @Ron I've added some clarifying details to the original post, with a screenshot of roughly what it should look like.

Comment: @CarolMcKay using numbers / "window.width" works on React Native, at least in my experience / to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

`resizeMode="contain"`  for the video

And `flex:1` for the style

Comment: Your answer is not at all clear. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: the prop to video 'resizeMode' needs to be set.  In IOS it defaults to "contain" but for android Ive foiund it doesnt and needs to be explicitly set, otherwise the video will not be scaled to the view it is in.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize another property `videoStyle` which lets you style the Video Component directly.

Add your style to that property, it should work

```
<Video ... videoStyle={{width: window.width, height: 650}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your Screen, your front-end could be designed like this.

```
return(
   <View style={{ width: "100%",height: "100%", flex: 1}}>
      <View style={{flex:0.7,justifyContent:'center'}}>
          <Video
           source={{ uri: url }}
           isMuted={false} 
           shouldPlay
           isLooping
           usePoster={true} 
           useNativeControls={false}
           />
       </View>
      <View style={{flex:0.1}}/>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{flex:0.1,paddingHorizontal:10}}>
           <View style={{width:"100%",justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center",backgroundColor:"blue"}}>
            <Text>Next</Text>
           </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
 )
```

Do not forget to import TouchableOpacity!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but when I tried this implementation, I found that the video wouldn't play at all if I set height to 100% or auto. The video element just disappeared.

Comment: ok, just use my above code as it is and check. Don't give height.

Comment: same result when I didn't give height, the component just disappears and the "next" button jumps to the top of the page (because the component seems to have 0 height)

Comment: I tried it again, still can't get it to work. It's like ignoring me telling it to stretch, and is instead only playing at native size.